# Letter E gets cut off when sending a WS message

Tags: python, json, websocket

I am having the weirdest bug. (Which probably has a perfectly logical explanation)
I am sending a connection message to Bitfinex platform. It is this:

```
ws.send(json.dumps({
    "event": "subscribe",
    "channel": "ticker",
    "pair": PAIR,
    }))
```

The PAIR variable is a pair of traded elements e.g. "EURUSD", "BTCEUR"...

The fun part is that this websocket request works perfectly with all strings EXCEPT for ones that begin with "E". One of the example responses I get with a string starting in E is this:

> {"channel":"ticker","pair":"URBTC","event":"error","symbol":"EURBTC","msg":"symbol:
>   invalid","code":10300}

notice the "pair" having "E" cut off, while "symbol" has the correct value. I have tried appending an extra string to the "pair" and adding an extra "symbol" element. None of that worked. I also tried encoding the string in ascii and utf-8, but that did nothing.

Anyone has any idea what this is?

P.S. this is an example of a positive response:

> {"event":"subscribed","channel":"ticker","chanId":9226,"symbol":"tBTCEUR","pair":"BTCEUR"}

Comment: Thats... fun.  It does the same with hardcoded values too?

Comment: @Phix Yup. exactly same thing.

Comment: Wild guess... have you tried a different key name? What's the python lib you're using? Also, I'm guessing this is consumed with a native websocket.on in the client ( if there is a client )

Comment: Sending the message uses websockets and json libs, both native iirc. It is consumed by a client over at wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws/2 , as I am trying to receive values from there.

Comment: Looking at the docs I don't see EURBTC as a supported pair.  Could have something to do with the `symbol: invalid` part of the message and the 10300 error code ("Subscription Failed [generic]"). Can you try `ETHUSD`?

Comment: ... I feel so embarrassed right now. That was it. Thank you! Sorry...

Comment: Yay! At least it's solved.